# Opening a PDF file using associated application in a Unity App for WindowsPhone 8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

I am pretty new in WindowsPhone applications development. I am currently developing a Unity application for Windows Phone 8.0. Inside this app I would like to open a PDF using the appropriate application on the phone (Acrobat Reader, Windows Reader, etc...)

First, I tried this :

```
void PDFButtonToggled(bool i_info)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            DefaultLaunch();
        });
    }

    async void DefaultLaunch()
    {
        // Path to the file in the app package to launch
        string PDFFilePath = @"Data/StreamingAssets/ImageTest.jpg";

        var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(PDFFilePath);

        if (file != null)
        {
            // Set the option to show the picker
            var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

            // Launch the retrieved file
            bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
            if (success)
            {
                // File launched
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("File launch failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find file");
        }
    }
```

It returned me an exception so I searched why. I found that topic (written in 2013 :/) about async functions / threads : [LINK](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cannot-return-values-from-async-methods.200562/). To sumarize, here the answer of Unity staff :

> It will only work on Windows Store Apps, and you'll have to wrap the code in #if NET_FX/#endif. On other platforms, you cannot use async/.NET 4.5 code in scripts. If you want to use it for windows phone, you'll have to write that code in separate visual studio solution and compile it to DLL, so unity can use it as a plugin.

So I decided to create the double DLL solution described in the Unity Manual here : [LINK](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/wp8-plugins-guide-csharp.html). But when I complete the class of the first DLL with the "async void DefaultLaunch()" function given above I don't have references about Windows.ApplicationModel.etc... and Windows.System.etc... .

And here I am, a little bit lost between WP, Unity, 8.0 apps, StoreApps, etc...
If anyone has advices, questions, anything that can help me, it's welcome. :)

Crèvecoeur

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself but on a WindowsPhone8.1 application.
Here it is :

```
        async void PDFButtonToggled(bool i_info)
    {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            DefaultLaunchFile();
        });
    }

    async void DefaultLaunchFile()
    {
        StorageFolder dataFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Data");
        StorageFolder streamingAssetsFolder = await dataFolder.GetFolderAsync("StreamingAssets");

        // Path to the file in the app package to launch
        string filePath = "PDFTest.pdf";

        var file = await streamingAssetsFolder.GetFileAsync(filePath);

        if (file != null)
        {

            // Launch the retrieved file
            bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
            if (success)
            {
                // File launched
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("File launch failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("File not found");
        }
    }
```